# How to remove priceLine Tradingview lightweight

Tags: tradingview-api

I try to remove priceLine from a chart. I'm using series.removePriceLine() but the line couldn't be removed.
Below are my code:

```
var weekpivot= {
          price: price.poc.weekR2.val,
          color: price.poc.weekR2.color,
          lineWidth: lineWidth,
          lineStyle: LightweightCharts.LineStyle.Solid,
          axisLabelVisible: true,
          title: price.poc.weekR2.title,
    };
const weeklyPivot = candlestickSeries.createPriceLine(weekpivot);
if(condition){
candlestickSeries.removePriceLine(weeklyPivot);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck ? I'm trying to remove the Priceline as well and cannot find how to do it.

Comment: @Curious101 - I dont find the actual solution. But i did a tweak by calling back the  my chart function but this time with empty array. Something like this: function (chart with priceline array) --> function (chart without priceline array).